# Using chromium with vulkan

Tags: chromium, vulkan

My system has 2 GPUs: Intel integrated, and AMD RX580. Both of these are found by `vulkan-info --summary` plus an additional cpu implementation.

```
Devices:
========
GPU0:
    apiVersion         = 1.3.238
    driverVersion      = 23.0.2
    vendorID           = 0x8086
    deviceID           = 0x4680
    deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_INTEGRATED_GPU
    deviceName         = Intel(R) UHD Graphics 770 (ADL-S GT1)
    driverID           = DRIVER_ID_INTEL_OPEN_SOURCE_MESA
    driverName         = Intel open-source Mesa driver
    driverInfo         = Mesa 23.0.2
    conformanceVersion = 1.3.0.0
    deviceUUID         = fd8cf190-0bdb-4dd5-b941-a7eb5b383e9c
    driverUUID         = 9bb8225e-db2e-6a20-282d-526794955fa9
GPU1:
    apiVersion         = 1.3.238
    driverVersion      = 23.0.2
    vendorID           = 0x1002
    deviceID           = 0x67df
    deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_DISCRETE_GPU
    deviceName         = AMD Radeon RX 580 Series (RADV POLARIS10)
    driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_RADV
    driverName         = radv
    driverInfo         = Mesa 23.0.2
    conformanceVersion = 1.2.7.1
    deviceUUID         = 00000000-0100-0000-0000-000000000000
    driverUUID         = 414d442d-4d45-5341-2d44-525600000000
GPU2:
    apiVersion         = 1.3.238
    driverVersion      = 0.0.1
    vendorID           = 0x10005
    deviceID           = 0x0000
    deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
    deviceName         = llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)
    driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_LLVMPIPE
    driverName         = llvmpipe
    driverInfo         = Mesa 23.0.2 (LLVM 15.0.7)
    conformanceVersion = 1.3.1.1
    deviceUUID         = 6d657361-3233-2e30-2e32-000000000000
    driverUUID         = 6c6c766d-7069-7065-5555-494400000000
```

Yet, when I try to use chromium with vulkan using `$ chromium --enable-features=Vulkan,webgpu`, I get:

```
Warning: vkCreateInstance: Found no drivers!
Error: vkCreateInstance failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
    at CheckVkSuccessImpl (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/VulkanError.cpp:88)
    at CreateVkInstance (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:416)
    at Initialize (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:302)
    at Create (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:232)
    at operator() (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:492)
```

What I tried:

- Using `--gpu-active-vendor-id=0x1001` on the command line to force AMD
- Using `--gpu-active-vendor-id=0x8086` on the command line to force Intel
- X11 vs Wayland
- google-chrome (r115) versus ubuntu chromium snap (r114)

Why do `vulkaninfo` and `chromium` contradict each other on the existance of vulkan drivers?

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel AlderLake-S GT1 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.8 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 44.2 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,radeon,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915 resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.2 renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 770
    (ADL-S GT1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/webgpu/comments/12xdxz2/any_ideas_why_webgpu_is_neither_working_in_chrome/) suggests using a different AMD driver.  It is possible that the application is using an instance extension that is not available on the current driver.

Answer (score 0):

So, 114 and 115 versions would not work.

When trying Google chrome 116.0.5845.32 I get working Vulkan:

[image: status]